# Weird freezes on Bionic

Tags: 18.04, freeze

I experience from time to time a weird freeze on Bionic, installed on a brand new Dell Inspiron 15 5000.

- The mouse still works
- Any music/sound keeps on playing. I haven't seen a video but out of current tabs a youtube thing was playing (sound was still) so presumably the video would still have been going.

  - Alt-tabs, to trying to bring up a new terminal doesn't work (no response)
  - Clicking on anything doesn't seem to have any effect. Tabs or windows won't come to the front or close or minimize, nor will any shortcut open anything.

Eventually I just go for a hard shutdown as there seems to be nothing else possible.

I suppose I could look at some logs to try to see what happened? Where would those be located?

===============

The last time this happened, not much was opened - I was watching something on youtube and nothing else opened (on Firefox). Then I try to launch Opera through terminal and opera failed to actually opened and the freeze happened.

However, right after restarting, I try to reproduce the problem (open something on youtube with Firefox, then launch opera through terminal) but it didn't occur. I tried a few time still with no freeze. So it would appear it's some sort of state that occur pseudo randomly (and perhaps not just a specific librairi/process)....

EDIT: as for shell extension as asked in comments (in other words - no it doesn't appear I have shell extension

```
anonymous@anonymous:~/.local/share/gnome-shell$ ls -al
total 12
drwx------  2 anonymous anonymous 4096 Dec 16 12:31 .
drwx------ 21 anonymous anonymous 4096 Dec 16 11:39 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 anonymous anonymous 2071 Dec 16 12:31 application_state


anonymous@anonymous:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8049336        0   8049336   0% /dev
tmpfs            1615924     2204   1613720   1% /run
/dev/sda2      100267080 24628032  70502664  26% /
tmpfs            8079608    38156   8041452   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8079608        0   8079608   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0        144384   144384         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop1         14976    14976         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop3         91648    91648         0 100% /snap/core/6034
/dev/loop2        157696   157696         0 100% /snap/opera/18
/dev/loop6        144128   144128         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop5         14848    14848         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
/dev/loop4         89088    89088         0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop7         35456    35456         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop8        157696   157696         0 100% /snap/opera/17
/dev/loop9         35584    35584         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop10         2304     2304         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop12        18048    18048         0 100% /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/9
/dev/loop11         2432     2432         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
/dev/loop13         3840     3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop14        13312    13312         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop15        13312    13312         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop16         3840     3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/sda1         523248     6228    517020   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs            1615920       20   1615900   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs            1615920       72   1615848   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop17       133760   133760         0 100% /snap/postman/80



anonymous@anonymous:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        3.3G        8.9G        462M        3.2G         11G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

Comment: Do you have any GNOME Shell extensions installed? Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema not it doesn't appear I have any extension installed - see above. It basically is whatever the straight download of Bionic on a flash drive would be, plus apt upgrade / apt update after...

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu out of a USB flash drive? All bets are off. Show me `free -h` and `df`.

Comment: No no no - it is fully installed. All I'm saying is that the state of the system is whatever the default configuration you get with the flash drive install of Ubuntu Bionic, plus whatever the upgrade/update gives you to get up to speed once that install is done.

Comment: You didn't show me `free -h` and `df`

Comment: Oups - corrected

Comment: It's actually a pretty new computer with an SSD and not that much installed yet. I'm a bit baffled by it. Happened 3 or 4 times over like 2 weeks

Comment: A brief look tells me that your swap may be too small, and you have {too many/and duplicate} snaps installed. Each one takes resources from a running system. I'd remove {most/all} of them and replace them with standard apps from the Ubuntu Software Store or Synaptic.